# How to add a value from variable to asp:ListItem in a asp:RadioButtonList

Tags: c#, .net

I have this code :

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="radInteresse" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem> 
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem></asp:ListItem> 
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

and I have these strings :

```
string var1="Only You";
string var2="Need Is";
string var3="Love";
```

now, I'd like to set the value of `var1` to the first `ListItem`, `var2` to the second and `var3` to the third.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this:

```
radInteresse.Items[0].Value = var1;
radInteresse.Items[2].Value = var2;
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use this:

```
<asp:RadioButtonList id="radInteresse" runat="server">         
</asp:RadioButtonList>
```

With this code-behind:

```
radInterese.DataSource = new[] { "Only You", "Need Is", "Love" };
radInterese.DataBind();
```

If you don't need to reference those ListItems directly.

The DataSource can be any array or enumerable collection, so these examples would work too:

```
radInterese.DataSource = new[] { var1, var2, var3 };
radInterese.DataBind();
```

Or

```
string[] myVars;  
// make sure you set the value of this array here
radInterese.DataSource = myVars;
radInterese.DataBind();
```

Or

```
List<string> myVars = new List<string>();  
// make sure you add items to this List here, e.g. myVars.Add(var1);
radInterese.DataSource = myVars;
radInterese.DataBind();
```

Answer (score 1):

Use as:

```
List<String> lst = new List<String>();
lst.Add("Only You");
lst.Add("Need Is");
lst.Add("Love");
RadioButtonList1.DataSource = lst;
RadioButtonList1.DataBind();
```